# How to list vCenter (VCSA) services in powershell / Powercli

Tags: rest, powershell, powercli, vcenter

I need to list the Linux-based vCenter (VCSA) Services in powercli / powershell script.
I don't know of any powercli cmdlet that will list the services.
I thought of using vSphere REST API newly introduced in vSphere 6.5

The two calls I tried using postman / vSphere API explorer failed with unable to authorize:

```
https://{server}/rest/vcenter/services

https://{server}/rest/appliance/services
```

I was able to use administrator@corp.local to list vms and create new vms, so I am not sure what's going on

Tested listing services using vSphere REST API in postman and REST explorer

```
 $url = "https://{server}/rest/vcenter/services"
Invoke-RestMethod -Method 'Get' -Uri $url -Credential $Cred
```

[VMware HOL screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KlEo.png)

My questions:
1) Is there a powercli command to list services in linux based vCenter (VCSA)
2) Any idea how to have this done using vSphere REST API

Comment: There's a service-control tool downloadable which you possibly use?

Comment: This might help https://www.virtuallyghetto.com/2017/01/exploring-new-vcsa-vami-api-wpowercli-part-1.html

Comment: Hi, the blog is for vSphere 6.5 which had VAMI REST API, I am using the latest vSphere 6.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below worked. Please use an SSO account when prompted for credentials and confirm the account use has privilege to view the services from vSphere client.

Check: https://communities.vmware.com/thread/618154

```
$vcenter = <vcsa-FQDN>
$BaseUri = "https://$vcenter/rest/"

$SessionUri = $BaseUri + "com/vmware/cis/session"

$Cred = Get-Credential

$auth = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($Cred.UserName + ':' + $Cred.GetNetworkCredential().Password))

$header = @{

    'Authorization' = "Basic $auth"

}

$authResponse = (Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Headers $header -Uri $SessionUri).Value

$sessionHeader = @{"vmware-api-session-id" = $authResponse }

$result = Invoke-Restmethod -Method Get -Headers $sessionHeader -Uri ($BaseUri + "vcenter/services")

$result.value.value | select Name_Key, Health, State, Description_Key
```